# Room - Add or Remove columns during runtime (at user end)?

Tags: android, excel, database, sqlite

I'm using a `room` database in my Android App. It is pretty much basic how I setup a table schema.

The application is about something related to data gathering and exporting to an Excel Sheet that has columns related to some users (illustrated in attachment).

[image: Image of the sample export from the app]

So, of course, this data will be in a single table.

I'd like to add an option to add or remove columns (add **Activity** **n** and remove **Activity** **m**) during runtime. Data would not be important if it is going to be lost, the application would ask the user to export the data first to an Excel Sheet *because it is going to be deleted during the operation of dropping the current table and creating a new table with the new schema*.

Also, I will then need another way for the DAO interfaces to access each cell by index without knowing what the cell actually is.

I think the data of the **columns** should be stored in a separate table? 
Any Ideas about how to achieve that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare Your columns as @Entity that are connected based on Your project. So 1 UID can have multiple activities, but one note and one date.

```
@Entity
public class Uid {
    @PrimaryKey //AutoGenerate if You want
    public int uID;
    public String notes;
    public String date;
}
```

and for activity class

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Uid.class,
        parentColumns = "uID",
        childColumns = "parentID",
        onDelete = CASCADE, onUpdate = CASCADE))
public class Activities {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
    public int parentID;
    public int someOtherNumber;
    }
```

So now if You delete your UID or update it all Activities will follow that behavior. You can also add and delete activities when You want. Just like in your excel. In this way You can ask dao to return Your activities connected to uID as List where You select one value by its index.